# DateTime.ParseExact is not working to convert a DateTime back and forth

Tags: c#, datetime, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to convert a DateTime to string back and forth to make sure there is no mistake in my code, but DateTime.ParseExact doesn't work.
It throws a `System.FormatException : String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.` exception.

This is the code I'm using:

```
// Example Input: Thu Aug 12 10:40:12 GMT-03:00 2021
const string dateFormat = "ddd MMM dd HH\':\'mm\':\'ss \'GMT\'K yyy";

string nowString = DateTime.Now.ToString(dateFormat, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
DateTime dateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(nowString, dateFormat, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

For some reason, the DateTime conversion to string is working perfectly, but the way back to DateTime is not.

I'm testing this on Unity 3D 2020.3.15f2, so Unity's implementation may be bugged...

Answer (score 3):

You just missed a `y` in your `dateFormat`

```
// Example Input: Thu Aug 12 10:40:12 GMT-03:00 2021
const string dateFormat = "ddd MMM dd HH\':\'mm\':\'ss \'GMT\'K yyyy";

string nowString = DateTime.Now.ToString(dateFormat, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
DateTime dateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(nowString, dateFormat, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: Wow. Thanks a lot, it worked! :) Shouldn't an exception be thrown on the `ToString` part? The output string works...

Comment: Ya. Sometimes going outside strict rules is forgiven (like when using Json strings). It is hard to understand why it allows it in one direction but not the reverse though

Comment: No exception is thrown from `ToString` because `yyy` is a valid specifier: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings#yyySpecifier